# How to understand TTL values in dig command output?

Tags: dns

I am reading about how **DNS** works in general. From the [wiki entry of TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live), I understand *TTL* (Time to Live) occur in the Domain Name System (**DNS**), where they are set by an authoritative name server for a particular resource record. When a caching (recursive) nameserver queries the authoritative nameserver for a resource record, it will cache that record for the time (in seconds) specified by the TTL.

Now, I needed to use the Linux CLI tools (`dig`) to figure out what is the actual TTL set in the authoritative name server and so used my command as below.

```
dig +trace +nocmd +noall +answer +ttlid a www.stackoverflow.com

#I have omitted the root name server output for better readability. 

www.stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CNAME   stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  A   198.252.206.140
;; Received 80 bytes from 173.245.59.4#53(cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com) in 9 ms
```

As I could see from the **A** record of `stackoverflow.com.`, the **TTL** value in the authoritative name server is 300.

So, does this mean, if I search for `stackoverflow.com` after 300 seconds or 5 minutes, the IP address of `stackoverflow.com` would be resolved all the way from the `.com` domain?

Answer (score 3):

No; not all the way from the `.com` domain (actually I think you meant from the root domain?).

The NS records for `stackoverflow.com` have a TTL of 172800, so those are cached a lot longer than the 300 seconds of the `www.stackoverflow.com` CNAME record and the `stackoverflow.com` A record. So after those CNAME and A records have expired, the NS records will probably still be cached and hence those nameservers can be questioned about `www.stackoverflow.com` (and then `stackoverflow.com`).

BTW I wouldn't have given both `www.stackoverflow.com` and `stackoverflow.com` a TTL of just 300, that means twice as many DNS requests without any immediately evident advantage IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. So, how can I find out the value of 172800 using the `dig` command?

Comment: If you leave out the `+noall +answer` from your `dig` command you also get the intermediate results and there you'll see the `TTL` for all entries found, including the nameservers.